# how to locate element present on table on webpage using selenium

Tags: selenium, html-table

How to get location of a particular column , how to get count of rows present on table

```
 <TR>
    <TD>Table Data</TD>
    <TD>More Table Data</TD>
    </TR>
    <TD>More Table Data</TD>
    <TD>Table Data</TD>
    </TR>
```

consider above as a table structure

Comment: Welcome to SO ! When posting a question, add the code related to your problem or what you tried to achieve what you want to do. It will help other to find a solution to your problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In *HTML code* snippet for Table you can notice that table is mainly form by two tags.
 **TR** and **TD**.

**TR** represents row in table and **TD** represents column in table.

Below are the simple code snippet which shows how to locate number of rows and columns present in table.

```
int Row_count = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/table/tbody/tr")).size();

System.out.println("Number Of Rows = "+Row_count);
```

**Note:** *Xpath* will vary always but tag */table/tbody/* will remain same in most cases.

```
int Col_count = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/table/tbody/tr[1]/td")).size();

System.out.println("Number Of Columns = "+Col_count);
```

**Note:***tr[1]/td* selects the first row in the table and gives all the columns present in the that table.

*In the same manner you can easily fetch any web-element present in the web table by changing your Xpath Logic.*

Answer (score -1):

Are there any attributes that you can use to identify the table?  Or will it require the index of the table elements?  Can you provide example url/html?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
table = soup.find("table", { "class" : class_name })
print len(table.findAll("tr"))
```

I typically find that using beautifulsoup / pandas dataframes easy for these types of problems.. example using wikipedia below:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2


car_data = pd.DataFrame()

model = 'Tesla_Model_S'

wiki = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{0}".format(model)
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} 
req = urllib2.Request(wiki,headers=header)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
table = soup.find("table", { "class" : "infobox hproduct" })

for row in table.findAll("tr")[2:]:
    try:
        field = row.findAll("th")[0].text.strip()
        val = row.findAll("td")[0].text.strip()
        car_data.set_value(model,field,val)
    except:
        pass

print car_data
```